# How do I change the beamer textcolor in itemize/enumerate to gray with alert staying in the predefined color?

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I want to give an overview of my presentation by listing the sections in an enumerate environment and highlighting each on a different slide by using:

```
   \begin{enumerate}
      \item<alert@2> Section A
      \item<alert@3> Section B
      \item<alert@4> Section C
      \item<alert@5> Section D
   \end{enumerate}
```

With this the normal text colour is black but I want it (when not alerted) to be grey.
A `\textcolor{grey}{}` block around the enumerate doesn't change anything, while this block for every item also changes the alert colour to grey.

I'd be happy for any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You cannot wrap `\textcolor{}` around complex code. But you could use `\color{gray}` just before the first `\item` (or directly after `\begin{enumerate}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot wrap `\textcolor{}` around an `enumerate` environment, but you can place `\color{gray}` just behind `\begin{enumerate}` to apply this color to all the text of the items inside this environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
    
    \begin{enumerate} \color{gray}
        \item<alert@2> Section A
        \item<alert@3> Section B
        \item<alert@4> Section C
        \item<alert@5> Section D
   \end{enumerate}
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]